# What is the difference between valueforKey:, objectForKey:, and valueForKeyPath:?

Tags: objective-c

I have 2 questions:

1. What is the difference between `valueForKey:` and `objectForKey:`? Is it that one is for `NSDictionary`s (`objectForKey:`) and for others it is `valueforKey:`, or is it the reverse?
2. Also what is the difference between `valueForKey:` and `valueForKeyPath:`? Has it got something to do with Core Data?

Please help.

Comment: similar question 


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/objective-c-whats-the-difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`valueForKey:` is part of the NSKeyValueCoding protocol and is therefore part of the key-value coding framework, which allows you to access class properties by name at runtime. That's how NIBs are loaded, for example — the names of properties associated with connections are loaded and then the values are set directly by name. This contrasts with the way that visual interface design tools often work in other languages, generating lots of hidden statically compiled code.

`objectForKey:` is defined on dictionaries only, and looks up an object by its key. An NSDictionary is a class that stores connections between values and keys.

So, `valueForKey:` could be used on an NSDictionary to return meta information about the dictionary, such as the count of objects inside it, the list of all keys, etc. `objectForKey:` would be used actually to look into the dictionary.

At runtime, the difference is that `objectForKey:` is a method with a completely opaque implementation. `valueForKey:` explicitly relies on subsequently calling named getters and setters. The reason for the latter is that you can extend key-value coding to key-value observing, where you ask to be informed every time a particular property on a particular object changes. At runtime that's achieved with a method swizzle, where the original setter is replaced by a new one that calls the previous setter and then sends out the required messages. Because all messages are dispatched dynamically, that's just achieved by modifying tables within the object instance.

So any object that is key-value coding compliant (which just means declaring and implementing your properties in the proper way, which the new-ish @property/@synthesize syntax does automatically) can be observed without the object itself having to implement any code.

There's further Apple stuff that uses key-value coding to achieve various things, including CoreData, but it's not specifically to enable any one other technology.

`valueForKeyPath:` is like `valueForKey:` except that it can traverse several objects. So you can have a root object with a bunch of properties, each of those properties is another object with another bunch of properties, etc, and using a key path you can retrieve a value way out at the leaf of that data structure rather than having to iterate through object after object for yourself.

In summary, `valueForKey:` and `valueForKeyPath:` provide information about object instances and interact with the dynamic nature of the Objective-C runtime. `objectForKey:` is a dictionary specific method that does dictionary tasks.

Additions:

An example, coded as I type and assuming that NSDictionary is key-value coding compliant:

```
NSDictionary *someDictionary;
// create someDictionary, populate it, for example (note: we assume photoOfKeys.jpg
// definitely exists, not a good idea for production code — if it doesn't we'll get
// a nil there and anything after it won't be added to the dictionary as it'll appear
// that we terminated the list):
someDictionary = @{ @"favouriteGarment": @"hat",
                    @"@allKeys"        : [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameDotMac],
                    @(2)               : NSArray.new };

NSObject *allKeys; 
// we make no assumptions about which type @allKeys will be,  but are going to assume
// we can NSLog it, so it needs to be a descendant of NSObject rather than 'id' so as 
// to definitely respond to the 'description' message — actually this is just compile
// time semantics, but if someone else reads this code it'll make it obvious to them 
// what we were thinking...

// some code to get all of the keys stored in the dictionary and print them out;
// should print an array containing the strings 'favouriteGarment', '@allKeys' and
// the number 2
allKeys = [someDictionary valueForKey:@"@allKeys"];
NSLog(@"%@", allKeys);

// some code to get the object named '@allKeys' from the dictionary; will print
// a description of the image created by loading photoOfKeys.jpg, above
allKeys = [someDictionary objectForKey:@"@allKeys"];
NSLog(@"%@", allKeys);
// `objectForKey is analogous to `objectForKeyedSubscript:`, aka
allKeys = someDictionary[@"@allKeys"];
```

`allKeys` is a property of NSDictionary as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/allKeys). I've also added a mapping from the NSString allKeys to a photograph of some keys. Whether I use the key-value coding `valueForKey:` methods or the NSDictionary `objectForKey:` lookup method dictates whether I read the property of the object instance or whether I send the object instance a message asking it to do its unique job.

Comment: I am a bit confused about using valueForKey: and objectForKey: on dictionary. When you say valueForKey could be used on an NSDictionary to return meta information about the dictionary, such as the count of objects inside it, the list of all keys, etc. 

Could you please show with an example as to what it would return so that I am a bit clear about the difference.

Comment: @hmthur Theres some good examples [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEEhttp://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE)

Comment: I think @"allKeys" should be @"@allKeys" in the example.

Comment: Tommy, you could have used a better example for the "allKeys" part ;) but very good explanation, I will +1. However I'm confused, should'nt the `@"@allKeys"` in snippets `[UIImage imageNamed:@"photoOfKeys.jpg"], @"@allKeys"` and `allKeys = [someDictionary objectForKey:@"@allKeys"];` be `@"allKeys"`, to better show the difference?

Comment: Isn't good to show the difference using a special key name like `@allKeys` and that in the case of `objectForKey:` it is not specially treated? that is, watch out which method you use as the same key can have different return values.

Comment: @hmthur However, sometimes, there is a practical difference which I don't understand clearly yet. `valueForKey` didn't work in SOGo-3.1.4's code trying to call an unavailable "method" `ASProtocolVersion` on the `context` object (`EXCEPTION: <NSException: 0x55f43f93e4d0> NAME:NSInvalidArgumentException REASON:-[WOContext ASProtocolVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`), whereas `objectForKey` works (and is the usual way to query the `context` object elesewhere in the code). See https://github.com/inverse-inc/sogo/pull/217/files

Answer (score 18):

1. `objectForKey:` is a method on `NSDictionary` for accessing the object associated with a key. `valueForKey:` is a method on `NSObject` for accessing any value associated with any object, through the name of a accessor method, property, and/or instance variable.
2. `valueForKeyPath:` can be seen as a shorthand for several calls to `valueForKey:`. You can think of it as sort of a xpath, if you will.

These two statements will result in the same output:

```
// Using nested valueForKey:
NSLog(@"%@", [[myObject valueForKey:@"foo"] valueForKey:@"bar"]);
// Can be done with a single valueForKeyPath;
NSLog(@"%@", [myObject valueForKeyPath:@"foo.bar"]);
```

`valueForKey:`and `valueForKeyPath:` are part of KVC (Key Value Coding). Introduction and in-depth documentation can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/

Answer (score 2):

1. `valueForKey:` and `valueAtKeyPath:` are methods defined in the `NSKeyValueCoding` informal  protocol, and default implementations for both are provided by the root class `NSObject`.

   `objectForKey:` is a method on `NSDictionary`.
2. `valueForKey:` takes a key to a property, while `valueAtKeyPath:` takes a so-called keypath. A keypath is a period-delimeted path to a specific property, like `@"relationship.property"`.