# Objective-C for Dummies: How do I get a value out of NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

so I'm having the most difficult of time pulling values out of an `NSDictionary`. Right now I just have a dictionary that is populated from a JSON call and it only contains a key named 'Success' with a value of 0 or 1.

How do I do a conditional on that value to check if its 0 or 1? I've tried a bunch of things, but I'm not getting anywhere. Here's my current code:

```
[[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Success"] isEqualToNumber:1]
```

I'm getting `passing argument 1 of 'isEqualToNumber:' makes pointer from integer without a cast'` as a warning, and the app crashes when it hits that line anyway.

And a subquestion, what's the difference between `objectForKey` and `valueForKey`? Which one should I use by default?

Anyway, this noob in Objective-C would truly appreciate some help on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Differences between `objectForKey` and `valueForKey` already has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489684/difference-valueforkey-objectforkey)

Comment: @Martin Nice answer there. I’ll favourite that question to keep it handy.

Comment: @Martin, thanks for the link, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since dictionaries contain Objective-C objects, an entry containing a number is an `NSNumber` instance. `NSNumber` provides a convenience method, `-intValue`, for extracting its underlying `int` value:

```
if ([[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Success"] intValue] == 1) { … }
```

Note that `NSNumber` has other convenience methods for extracting its underlying value as other C data types.

---

**In most cases, you should use `-objectForKey:` instead of `-valueForKey:`.** The former is the canonical method to obtain an entry in the dictionary and is declared in `NSDictionary`. The latter is declared in `NSObject` and is used in Key-Value Coding contexts, where the key must be a valid KVC key, and there’s additional processing — for instance, if you’re using `-valueForKey:` in a dictionary with a key that starts with @, that character is stripped from the key and `[super valueForKey:key]` is called.

Comment: you've saved me once again, thanks! The conditional works and now I gotta figure out how to act on. Objective-C has been a *slow* learning experience for me...

Comment: @Alex Cheers. Be warned that `-intValue` will return `0` if the key is not in the dictionary, though. In some cases I first grab the object from the dictionary (e.g. `NSNumber *success = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Success"];`) and test if it’s different from `nil` to make sure the key was available in the dictionary in the first place. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

The number 1 is not an object pointer.  Use an NSNumber instance instead if you want to use a number in an NSDictionary.

```
[[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Success"]
 isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Success"] isEqualToNumber: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]
```

- Number and Value Programming Topics: [Using Numbers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Numbers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000175-BCIFIJIE)
- [NSNumber: What is the point ?](http://objcolumnist.com/2009/05/31/nsnumber-what-is-the-point/)

Answer (score 0):

> You can get the value of dictionary in different ways like checking
>   the value first.

```
Solution 1: Using simple if statement.
int value = 0;
if ([[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Success"]intValue]==1){
    value = [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Success"]intValue];
}

Solution 2: Using ternary operator
value = ([[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Success"]intValue]==1) ? 1:0;
```