# setObject ForKey

Tags: cocoa

I am attempting to incorporate a plist into my project. I have accomplish the extraction of the data from the plist to my project. Now I want to write back the modified data. For instance, I have a textField in which the data is stored as an integer. Now I want to capture that integer data and store it in an NSMutable Dictionary *temp using:

```
[temp setObject:<what goes here?> forKey:@"key"];
```

prior to writing it all out to the plist. All I end up getting is the pointer information and not the value of the textField into the dictionary. I am using the following to examine the dictionary:

```
for (id key in temp) {
 NSLog(@"entry %@ value %@", key, [temp valueForKey:key]);
}
```

Comment: Jim Rogers learning Cocoa. Sounds reasonable. After all, Cocoa is a commodity!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something like:

```
[temp setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[textField integerValue]] forKey:@"key"];
```

if you're coding for OS X.

Or something like:

```
[temp setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[textField.text integerValue]] forKey:@"key"];
```

if you're coding for iOS.

Just to make sure OP doesn't miss **edc1591**'s comment: NSDictionary implements a method [objectForKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which should be used in favor of the generic KVC method [valueForKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489684/difference-valueforkey-objectforkey/4489859#4489859) for more info on `objectForKey:` vs. `valueForKey:`

Edit: Overlooked OP mentioning the values being integers. Fixed answer.
Edit: Added remark on valueForKey: usage.

Comment: The OP said <quote>...I want to capture that integer data...</quote>. Seems like `[temp setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[textField integerValue]] forKey:@"key"];` would be better.

Comment: also, he needs to use `objectForKey:` not `valueForKey:` when reading from the dictionary

Comment: @edc1591: yeah, noticed it, but ignored it since it wasn't strictly related to OPs question/problem. But you're totally right, of course. Added a remark to my answer.