# Prons and Cons of using objectForKey and valueForKey?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

As I know there is difference between `objectForKey` and `valueForKey`.

`objectForKey:` datatype is :`(id)aKey` whereas `valueForKey:` datatype is :`(NSString *)key`.

I know that this topic already discussed on `stackoverflow` but that is not provide me satisfaction. so please do not mark as `duplicated`

I already referred :

[Difference between objectForKey and valueForKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey)

[What is the difference between valueforKey:, objectForKey:, and valueForKeyPath:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489684/what-is-the-difference-between-valueforkey-objectforkey-and-valueforkeypath)

Finally `NSString` is also type of `id`. so why apple provide `valueForKey` over `objectForKey`. i think there is some performance problem or any other. my question is if `objectForKey` satisfied all requirement of `valueForKey` then what is need of `valueForKey`?

Comment: It doesn't, what didn't you understand from looking at the first linked answer you gave - they are used for different things

Comment: what is difference situation where they are used separately? like once i used 'valueForKey' if i have `NSString` as `key`. in this place i can used `objectForKey` as well. is there any situation where they are not getting each other place?

Comment: It isn't about the key type, it's about the receiver being a dictionary or any other object (so KVC)

Comment: so can you please show me the different situation where they are used separately means they are not taking each other place?

Comment: the typo in the title of this question is hilarious

Comment: As I understand it , `valueForKey:` is [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001838-SW1), but can be used to return objects in an NSDictionary, obviously `NSDictionary` overrides the `valueForKey:` method. `objectForKey:` is the designated method for retrieving values from an `NSDictionary` see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/valueForKey:)

Comment: @RASS, of course, but my question is `What is prons and cons when i am using objectForKey and valueForKey has data type NSString`?

Comment: However, sometimes, there is a practical difference which I don't understand clearly yet. `valueForKey` didn't work in SOGo-3.1.4's code trying to call an unavailable "method" `ASProtocolVersion` on the `context` object (`EXCEPTION: <NSException: 0x55f43f93e4d0> NAME:NSInvalidArgumentException REASON:-[WOContext ASProtocolVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`), whereas `objectForKey` works (and is the usual way to query the `context` object elesewhere in the code). See https://github.com/inverse-inc/sogo/pull/217/files