# How to detect if NSString is null?

Tags: objective-c, null, nsnull

I have a piece of code that detects if a `NSString` is `NULL`, `nil`, etc. However, it crashes. Here is my code:

```
NSArray *resultstwo = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM processes WHERE ready='yes' LIMIT 0,1"];
for (NSDictionary *rowtwo in resultstwo) {

NSString *getCaption = [rowtwo valueForKey:@"caption"];

if (getCaption == NULL) {
theCaption = @"Photo uploaded...";
} else if (getCaption == nil) {
theCaption = @"Photo uploaded...";
} else if ([getCaption isEqualToString:@""]) {
theCaption = @"Photo uploaded...";
} else if ([getCaption isEqualToString:@" "]) {
theCaption = @"Photo uploaded...";
}

}
```

And here's the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSInvalidArgumentException`', reason: '`-[NSNull isEqualToString:]`: unrecognized selector sent to instance `0x3eba63d4`'

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to do it a different way?

Comment: What’s the data type of `rowtwo`? Why are you sending it `-valueForKey:`?

Comment: I’ll leave this comment for further reference: `-valueForKey:` is a KVC method. In KVC, `[NSNull null]` represents the absence of a value for a given key. If you’re using an `NSDictionary` in a context that doesn’t need KVC, use `-objectForKey:` instead — it will return `nil` instead of `[NSNull null]` when a given key is not present in the dictionary.

Comment: See this Stack Overflow question for a discussion on the difference between `-valueForKey:` and `-objectForKey:`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/objective-c-whats-the-difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey

Comment: Getting object from array populated by a database...

Comment: `rowtwo` is not an array, otherwise `-valueForKey:` would return another array. Is it a dictionary?

Comment: Please see my edits in how I populated it and used a NSDictionary.

Comment: It’s a dictionary, then. See my comments #2 and #3.

Comment: One more note (ha! :-)) — it looks like you’re using some non-Apple class to fetch results from a database query. If a column is NULL (as in SQL NULL), this class has two options when populating a dictionary: either don’t include the corresponding key, or include the corresponding key mapping to an `[NSNull null]` value. So it is up to this class how to represent SQL NULL values, and your test needs to consider the specifics of this class.

Comment: You can check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51626469/3378413

Answer (score 174, accepted):

The `NULL` value for **Objective-C objects** (type `id`) is `nil`.

While `NULL` is used for **C pointers** (type `void *`).

(In the end both end up holding the same value (`0x0`). They differ in type however.)

In **Objective-C**:

- `nil` *(all lower-case)* is a null
  pointer to an **Objective-C object**.
- `Nil` *(capitalized)* is a null pointer
  to an **Objective-C class**.
- `NULL` *(all caps)* is a null pointer to
  anything else *(**C pointers**, that is)*.
- `[NSNull null]` is a **singleton** for situations where **use of nil is not possible** (adding/receiving nil to/from `NSArray`s e.g.)

In **Objective-C++**:

- **All of the above**, plus:
- `null` *(lowercase)* or `nullptr` (**C++11** or later) is a null pointer to **C++ objects**.

---

So to check against `nil` you should either compare against `nil` (or `NULL` respectively) **explicitly**:

```
if (getCaption == nil) ...
```

or let **ObjC** / **C** do it **implicitly** for you:

```
if (!getCaption) ...
```

This works as every expression in **C** (and with **Objective-C** being a superset thereof) has an implicit boolean value:

```
expression != 0x0 => true
expression == 0x0 => false
```

---

Now when checking for `NSNull` this obviously wouldn't work as `[NSNull null]` returns a pointer to a singleton instance of `NSNull`, and not `nil`, and therefore it is not equal to `0x0`.

So to check against `NSNull` one can either use:

```
if ((NSNull *)getCaption == [NSNull null]) ...
```

or (preferred, see comments):

```
if ([getCaption isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ...
```

---

Keep in mind that the latter (utilising a message call) will return `false` if `getCaption` happens to be `nil`, which, while formally correct, might not be what you expect/want.

Hence if one (for whatever reason) needed to **check against both** `nil`/`NULL` **and** `NSNull`, one would have to combine those two checks:

```
if (!getCaption || [getCaption isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ...
```

---

For help on forming **equivalent positive checks** see [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and [boolean negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation).

**Edit:** [NSHipster.com](http://nshipster.com/nil/) just published a great article on the subtle differences between nil, null, etc.

Comment: True, although the actual error is that `[rowtwo valueForKey:@"caption"]` is returning an `NSNull` instance instead of an `NSString` instance.

Comment: @Bavarious: See last line in answer.

Comment: @phpnerd211: this probably doesn't solve your real problem, though -- see Bavarious's comments attached to the question.

Comment: He was mistaken. I use this method all over my app and it functions properly -- see my edits in my code on how I populated the array, etc.

Comment: @phpnerd211 I advise you not to use `-valueForKey:` because it serves a different purpose. If you’re using `NSDictionary`, use its `-[NSDictionary objectForKey:]` method. If you want to learn more about KVC and `-valueForKey:`, there are a couple of guides on Apple’s web site.

Comment: getCaption == [NSNull null] is a bad idea to use.  It's better to do [getCaption class] == [NSNull class].  You're free to create new instances of NSNull and some JSON parsers do make new ones instead of using the singleton.

Comment: I found that using '(getCaption == [NSNull null])' worked fine but got a comparison warning so I changed it to 'if (getCaption == (id)[NSNull null])'

Comment: I had to check for NSNull as well, strange. Seems my NSString was set

Comment: perfect answer , Clear

Comment: Bless you! Perfect answer!

Answer (score 24):

You should use

`if ([myNSString isEqual:[NSNull null]])`

This will check if object myNSString is equal to NSNull object.

Comment: Since NSNull is a singleton, you could actually compare pointers directly: `if (getCaption == [NSNull null])...`

Comment: But comparing against the singleton is a bad idea!  Don't do it =X.  [NSNull null] may be a singleton but NSNull is a class like any other.

Answer (score 6):

Preferred Way to check for the `NSNULL` is

```
if(!getCaption || [getCaption isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if([getCaption class] == [NSNull class])
    ...
```

You can also do

```
if([getCaption isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    ...
```

if you want to be future proof against new subclasses of NSNull.

Comment: Of all the answers on this page, only your top answer is working for me in Xcode 6.1, using an NSString property called `body` that's null. Debugger output: `_body NSString * class name = NSNull 0x0000000107279ce0` and `Printing description of ad->_body: <null>`

Answer (score 2):

Just check with this code:

```
NSString *object;

if(object == nil)
```

This should work.