# When does Objective-C implicitly cast to BOOL?

Tags: objective-c, boolean, type-conversion

I read [Mike Ash's Objective-C pitfalls page](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-12-14-objective-c-pitfalls.html), and now I'm paranoid about implicitly casting variables of type `id` to `BOOL`.

Assume I have a 'dangerous' pointer with the lower bits zeroed out, so that casting it to a `BOOL` would produce `NO` even though it points to a valid object. Let's call this 'dangerous' pointer `foo`.

How do simple if statements work?
Does the if statement cast `foo` to a `BOOL` when it evaluates the condition? Or does it cast to a pure boolean?

```
if( foo )
{
  [myArray addObject:foo];
}
```

Does it work the same way in ternary expressions?

```
// Does this break when foo is 'dangerous'?
self.titleLabel.hidden = foo ? YES : NO ;
```

Or will the ternary only break if I do this:

```
// I'm pretty sure it breaks now
self.titleLabel.hidden = ((BOOL)foo) ? YES : NO ;
```

I feel like I'm missing something basic about logical operations in C, and how they relate to `BOOL`. Please help enlighten me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `if ( foo )` is equivalent to `if ( foo != 0 )`, it's not casting `foo` to a boolean... cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6177766/210171

Comment: I believe the second option is also fine, because again the equivalent is `(foo != 0) ? YES : NO`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When does Objective-C implicitly cast to BOOL?

Never, since this phrase is semantically incorrect. A cast is, by definition, explicit. What you're asking about is called an "implicit type conversion" (coercion - thanks, Josh!).

Also, strictly speaking, the conditionals in Objective-C are not special: they're inherited from C. So expressions, when needed to evaluated as booleans, aren't treated as `BOOL`, but as `int`.

```
// Does this break when foo is 'dangerous'?`
self.titleLabel.hidden = foo ? YES : NO;
```

No, it doesn't. `(expr)` when used as a "boolean" expression, is equivalent to `(expr != 0)`. No risks here.

```
// I'm pretty sure it breaks now
self.titleLabel.hidden = ((BOOL)foo) ? YES : NO;
```

Now this can break, since `BOOL` is just typedeffed to `signed char`, which is 8 bit on iOS. Thus, if `foo`, which is a (32-bit) pointer, gets truncated to 8 bits, and the lower 8 bits of the pointer were all zero, but the pointer itself wasn't `nil`, this will incorrectly report false. You don't want to do this superfluous, ugly and dangerous cast. If you want to be more explicit, write

```
var = (obj != nil) ? valueOne : valueTwo;
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's no casting in your first two samples. Writing if(expr) is equal to writing if(expr == 0).

Your third example might indeed break in some cases, as described in the article you refer to.