# how to Check NSString is null or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I want to check weather a `NSString` is null or not. Im assigning from an JSON array. After assigning that string value is `<null>`. Now I want to check this string is null or not. So I put like this

`if (myStringAuthID==nil)` but this if statement always false. How I can check a string for null. Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Your code should have worked. Try printing the value `NSLog(@"'%@'", myStringAuthID)` to see what's there.

Comment: do you just mean an empty string like `@""`?

Comment: http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/09/better-way-to-check-empty-string.html

Comment: if(mystring==NULL){}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41522199/5672017

Comment: you can check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51626469/3378413

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Like that:

```
[myString isEqual: [NSNull null]];
```

Comment: No need to use `isEqual`.  `==` works just fine, since `[NSNull null]` is a singleton.

Comment: Create a category on NSString and include this method:
```+ (BOOL)isEmpty:(NSString *)string
{return !string || [string isEqual:[NSNull null]] || [string isEqualToString:@""];}```

Comment: if (myString == (NSString*)[NSNull null]) if you do not cast it then there is a warning just pointing that out.  The pointers are different types.

Answer (score 10):

There are three possible interpretations of "null" NSString:

1. `someStringPtr == nil`
2. `(id)someStringPtr == [NSNull null]`
3. `someStringPtr.length == 0`

If you may have the possibility of all 3, the 3rd check subsumes the first, but I don't know of a simple check for all three.

In general, JSON will return `[NSNull null]` for a `null` JSON value, but some kits may return `@""` (length == 0) instead.  `nil` will never be used in iOS since it can't be placed in arrays/dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Try `if(myString == [NSNull null])`. That should evaluate it properly.

Comment: when I type like that there was a warning saying comparison between distinct pointer types (NSString and NSNull) is it ok?

Comment: try you've try with my code?

Comment: This is not the best approach. You should use `isEqual`

Comment: Both have been fine for me, I've tried. The `==` comparison operator checks to see if they're the same object, and as `NSNull null` is always the same object it should always work (unless Apple subtly changes something).

Comment: @Bot not totally true, NSNull is a singleton that gives you always the same pointer, so if myString pointer points to [NSNull null] is safe and also faster to make an comparison check between pointer values.

Comment: @Andrea Keep in mind that this relies on an implementation detail. While it may work at the moment, using `isEqual:` is safer and does not depend on an implementation detail.

Comment: @rmaddy - Not an "implementation detail" -- it's in the spec for NSNull.

Comment: == does not match NSNull to NSString

Answer (score 1):

I think that is best if you check  before cast it to an NSString or whatever, you have different options, the above are correct, but I prefer this:

```
id NilOrValue(id aValue) {
  if ((NSNull *)aValue == [NSNull null]) {
    return nil;
  }
  else {
    return aValue;
  }
}
```

Using this snippet (pay attention that is a C function) before passing the value to a pointer you can safely pass a value or nil if the value in NSNull. Passing nil is great, because if you send a message to a nil object, it doesn't throw an exception. You can also check for class type with `-isKindOfClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is part of a string category I created:

```
@interface NSString (Enhancements)

+(BOOL)isNullOrEmpty:(NSString *)inString;

@end

@implementation NSString (Enhancements)

+(BOOL)isNullOrEmpty:(NSString *)inString
{
    BOOL retVal = YES;

    if( inString != nil )
    {
        if( [inString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )
        {
            retVal = inString.length == 0;
        }    
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"isNullOrEmpty, value not a string");
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}

@end
```

Comment: `inString != nil` is a comparison between a pointer and an integer, means this is not recommended