# How to check if (id) object is null in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, afnetworking, nsnull

I have made a function to consume webservices , now I want to check if (id) object is null or not. What I am doing is here:

```
-(void)callService:(NSString*)request param:(NSString*) parameters completion:(void (^)(NSArray *list, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
    [self.manager POST:request parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"Response Object: %@", responseObject);

        if (![responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {

            [self methodUsingJsonFromSuccessBlock:responseObject];

            if (completionHandler) {
                //NSLog(@"%@", list);
                completionHandler(list,nil);
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Nothing found");
        }
    }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

        //NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(nil,error);
        }
    }];
}
```

but what I have found on break points is when (id) is null it has NSZeroData but no NSNull so it always passes my condition. I am using `AFNetworking`

[image: Heres the details of response object:]

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557392/how-to-check-the-null-value-in-nsstring-in-ios

Comment: what about if you just set if(responseObject){do next task}else{nothng found}

Comment: did this it never stops at this condition.

Comment: What if you change your condition to `if (![responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && ![responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSZeroData class]])` ?

Comment: `if (responseObject != nil)` is that help?

Comment: @MQ. can you please put the json which you are parsing with null object.. So i can try in my code...

Comment: NSzerodata is not accepted by xcode, it gives me error use of undec... @Jasper

Comment: did this too @RemingHsu

Comment: I see, didn't know that. You might want to try to cast to NSData (or another object) before doing any checks then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `responseObject` is not `NSNull`, but an `NSData` (which `_NSZeroData` is a subclass of).

So what you really want is this condition:

```
if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSData class]] && ((NSData *)responseObject).length > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Note that `_NSZeroData` is just a special `NSData` that is always 0 length.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the fastest response, but it can be of some use to someone.

Here is what I've been using and what you can do:

In some class, say "defaults.h" you can define following:

```
#define Secure(x) x != (id)[NSNull null] ? x : @""
#define isSecure(x) x != (id) [NSNull null] ? YES : NO
```

Later, in your method you can use it like this:

```
if(isSecure(responseObject)){
    doSuccess
}
else {
    doError
}
```

First method can be used for example for strings, while the other is general.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

Put this on top

```
#define isNSNull(value) [value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]
```

And then while comparing

```
if (isNSNull(object) ...
```

Comment: He states in his question that the value is not NSNull.

Comment: if it is not null then he can write it in else part.

Comment: If u can check now i have add a picture too

Comment: @PradumnaPatil 
Did you seen the condition which MQ. has defined in his code. 
If yes then can you please explain what is the difference between your condition and his condition..
As per my knowledge both is doing same thing.. .

Comment: Not sure how the else case will help him out

Comment: Both conditions are exactly same  @pradumna