# what's the bulletproof method to check if NSString is empty/null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

jI am building an app where I want to show  cleaner's contact information in a UIButton if a cleaner has been assigned to a job, and not show that UIButton otherwise. I have "appointment" objects that have cleaner and cleanerPhone strings as properties. I tried using this to check whether to print  string:

```
if(appt.cleanerPhone)
```

But this prints the button with a null phone number which isn't helpful. So then I tried

```
if([appt.cleanerPhone length]>2)
```

That was working yesterday but just started crashing my app with this error message pointing to the line above:

```
2015-04-22 18:59:07.165 [640:158880] -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x37afd690
```

I also tried

```
if(appt.cleanerPhone && [appt.cleanerPhone length]>2)
```

But this leads to the same error.

For reference, these all come from a parsed JSON object->NSDictionary. If there is no cleaner, here's what the NSDictionary shows in NSLog:

```
    cleaner = "<null>";
    cleanerPhone = "<null>";
```

So how can I safely and robustly check if a string object of my Appointment class is non-empty? And what's wrong with the two methods above?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684157/how-to-detect-if-nsstring-is-null and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546920/how-to-check-nsstring-is-null-or-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting data from JSON or another data interchange format. The conversion makes `null` into `[NSNull null]` objects. You need to type check the value before you use it. Try:

```
if ([appt.cleanerPhone isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && ([appt.cleanerPhone length] > 2)) {...}
```

Comment: To explicitly check for NSNull, compare with `==` to `[NSNull null]`.

Comment: if ([strpass isEqual:[NSNull null]] || strpass==nil || [strpass isEqualToString:@"<null>"] || [strpass isEqualToString:@"(null)"] || strpass.length==0 || [strpass isEqualToString:@""])
{
    //string is blank  
}