# Checking to see if ObjectForKey exists

Tags: objective-c

I have been tasked with cleaning up someone else's Objective-C (iOS) code. My Objective-C chops are a bit rusty, so I am hoping you all can verify something for me.

The person who coded the project that I am tasked with cleaning up, seems to be handling a nil object check multiple different ways.  I just want to be clear that all of the following actually behave the same way, and there is not some little nuance I am missing.

**Method 1**

```
if ([completeProdDict objectForKey:@"specialInstructions"])// does object for key exist
```

**Method 2**

```
if (nil !=[completeProdDict objectForKey:@"specialInstructions"])// does object for key exist
```

**Method 3**

```
if ([completeProdDict objectForKey:@"specialInstructions"] !=nil)// does object for key exist
```

Is my assumption that all of these behave the same way, correct?

```
// does object for key exist
```

couldn't **Method 1** just be used?

Comment: Yes - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177719/testing-for-nil-in-objective-c-ifx-nil-vs-ifx

Comment: thank you.. I looked for a duplicate and it didn't come up. thank you

Comment: it could be. choosing any of them depends on which style is better for your eyes when you read the code.