# Why cannot we use the negation operator when checking for the existence of a symbol?

Tags: objective-c, null, weak-linking, weak-symbol

The answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177719/testing-for-nil-in-objective-c-ifx-nil-vs-ifx) state that `if (x != nil)` is the same as `if (x)`.

But [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html) reads:

> Note: When checking for the existence of a symbol, you must explicitly compare it to NULL or nil in your code. You cannot use the negation operator ( ! ) to negate the address of the symbol.

Which seems to contradict "Working with nil" from https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW22

Comment: Have you tried the negation(!) ever to check the existence of a  symbol? What  error does it throw?

Comment: @RajeevRanjan no error, it works for me. So Apple documentation is confusing.

Comment: Ok. so its in line as I had been speculating.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is stating that you can't negate the address. In other words, you can't do this:

```
if (!MyWeakLinkedFunction) {
    // symbol doesn't exist
}
```

You must instead do:

```
if (MyWeakLinkedFunction == NULL) {
    // symbol doesn't exist
}
```

However, both of these work:

```
if (MyWeakLinkedFunction) {
    // symbol exists
}
```

or:

```
if (MyWeakLinkedFunction != NULL) {
    // symbol exists
}
```

Comment: So, despite `NULL` being (most likely) _defined_ as `(void*) 0`, applying the negation operator to that does not give something that evaluates to `true`?

Comment: @NicolasMiari I don't understand your question. The negation operator isn't be applied to `NULL` anywhere in my answer.

Comment: I just assumed that if `MyWeakLinkedFunction == NULL` evaluates to `true`, then `MyWeakLinkedFunction` should be actually `NULL` (a.k.a. `0`), and negating that would give `true`. I mean, it still isn't clear **why** `! MyWeakLinkedFunction` isn't meaningful/allowed.

Comment: @NicolasMiari I'm not 100% sure but I think it has to do with the fact that it is a runtime check for the existing of a weakly linked function so the negation doesn't quite work as one might expect with a "normal" pointer.

Comment: I see. I don't know all the implementation details of weak linking at compile time/run time, but it would be an interesting read. I'll do some research...

Comment: @rmaddy, I do not get why `if (MyWeakLinkedFunction)` would be working as expected, but not `if (!MyWeakLinkedFunction)`.

Comment: As I said in my reply to Nicolas, I'm not really sure why. It's Apple's statement. I'm simply clarifying their statement in my answer to your question. I do know that `if (MyWeakLinkedFunction)` works because I use that in several places in my own app. I don't I've actually tried the negation because I'm always checking if the symbol exists.

Comment: If the expression is treated as a BOOL, the symbol could exist and `! symbol` could evaluate to `TRUE`.  I believe Mike Ash has a post about it, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, we might just be overthinking.

> When checking for the existence of a symbol, you must explicitly
>   compare it to NULL or nil in your code.

This part only says - If you want to check for the existence(and not the non-existence), you must explicitly compare to `NULL` or `NIL`

> You cannot use the negation operator ( ! ) to negate the address of
>   the symbol.

If you succeed negating the address of the symbol, its only that you land up successfully checking the non-existence(and not the existence).

When i came across the following, I thought this might be a possibility as they use the word availability [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html) -

> Note: To check the availability of a function, explicitly compare its
>   address to NULL or nil. You cannot use the negation operator ( ! ) to
>   negate the address of a function to check its availability. Also, note
>   that the name of a C function is synonymous with its address. That is,
>   &myFunction is equivalent to myFunction.