# Is nil and (NSString *)[NSNull null] equivalent in checking empty NSString object

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, null, nsnull

I have a `NSString` object,

```
NSString *aString;
```

then are the two following versions equivalent?

**Version 1 :**

```
if ( (NSString *)[NSNull null] == aString )
{
   // Logic handling
}
```

**Version 2 :**

```
if ( nil == aString )
{
   // Logic handling
}
```

### Reference Posts

1. [Difference among nil, Nil, and null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908936/iphonedifference-between-nil-nil-and-null)
2. [How to detect if NSString is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684157/how-to-detect-if-nsstring-is-null)
3. [Apple's NSNull Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
4. [How do I test if a string is empty in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899209/how-do-i-test-if-a-string-is-empty-in-objective-c)

### Update - Test Result

My simple test result shows that the above two versions have different behaviors:

1. When `aString` is initialized and then assigned with `nil`:

   `false` for expression in version 1,

   `true` for expression in version 2.
2. When `aString` is initialized with the value of `@""`.

   `false` for expression in version 1,

   `false` for expression in version 2.

So it's clear that the two versions are not equivalent in their behavior.

The test code:

```
NSString *aString = nil;
NSString *bString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

if ((NSString *)[NSNull null] == aString) {
    NSLog(@"a1 - true");
} else {
    NSLog(@"a1 - false");
}

if (nil == aString) {
    NSLog(@"a2 - true");
} else {
    NSLog(@"a2 - false");
}

if ((NSString *)[NSNull null] == bString) {
    NSLog(@"b1 - true");
} else {
    NSLog(@"b1 - false");
}

if (nil == bString) {
    NSLog(@"b2 - true");
} else {
    NSLog(@"b2 - false");
}
```

Console output:

```
2013-10-31 00:56:48.132 emptyproject[31104:70b] a1 - false
2013-10-31 00:56:48.133 emptyproject[31104:70b] a2 - true
2013-10-31 00:56:48.133 emptyproject[31104:70b] b1 - false
2013-10-31 00:56:48.133 emptyproject[31104:70b] b2 - false
```

### Update - What Do I Mean "Empty string"**

Now I've made it clearer that it's different for a `NSString` object to be `nil` and for it to be a valid initialized instance holding an empty string value of `@""`. What I really need in this post is that how to test if my `NSString` object is successfully initialized, that is, if `aString` is `nil`. I want to know if there is any difference for the above two versions of test code.

Comment: How could they be equivalent?

Comment: To @Sulthan, so I can't replace `if ( aString == (NSString *)[NSNull null] )` with `if ( aString == nil )`?

Comment: No. What are you trying to do?

Comment: To @Sulthan, Trying to check an empty string, `@""`.

Comment: Also, you can replace `if ( aString == nil )` by `if (!aString)`

Comment: @congliu The best check for empty string is `aString.length == 0`

Comment: To @Sulthan, Does `[aString length]` also yields `0` even if `aString` fails to get initialized? For example, by this initialization code: `NSString *aString = [aNSMutableDictionaryVariable objectForKey:@"stringKey"];` and right after this initialization, there goes the check code `aString` with `if (0 == [aString length]){}`

Comment: To @JordanMontel, Do you mean `aString == nil` is wrong but `!aString` is correct? Or do you mean they're equivalent, but the latter is better since it's simpler?

Comment: it's equivalent but you tape less code :)

Comment: @congliu You should parse dictioaries smartly. Use a category on `NSDictionary` to convert `NSNull` to `nil` automatically.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`[NSNull null]` and `nil` are not equivalent. `[NSNull null]` is meant to represent the concept of NULL (as in no object) in cases where `nil` cannot be used, for example in an `NSArray` (as you can only insert objects in them). `[NSNull null]` is an object (always the same object), while `nil` is a pointer to 0.

NSHipster has a nice discussion [here](http://nshipster.com/nil/). He says:

> NSNull is used throughout Foundation and other frameworks to skirt
>   around the limitations of collections like NSArray and NSDictionary
>   not being able to contain nil values. You can think of NSNull as
>   effectively boxing the NULL or nil value so that it can be used in
>   collections.

If you have:

```
NSString *aString;
if ( aString == (NSString *)[NSNull null] )
{
   // Logic handling
}
```

then something's wrong, `aString` should point to an `NSString` object (or subclass), or `nil`. But not `[NSNull null]` which is an object of a different class, you shouldn't cast from one to the other.

**EDIT:**

Given in the comments you state that you wish to check if the string is empty (as in `@""`), that is different. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899209/how-do-i-test-if-a-string-is-empty-in-objective-c). An empty string is an `NSString` object, it is not `nil` and it is not `[NSNull null]`.

Comment: To @jbat100, now I've made it clearer that it's different for a `NSString` object to be `nil` and for it to have `@""`. So what I really need in the post is that how to test if my `NSString` object is successfully initialized, that is, if `aString` is `nil`.

Comment: if (aString == nil) {//string is not initialized}

Comment: if (aString != nil) {//string is initialized}

Comment: "then something's wrong" The "something wrong" could be laziness. Sometimes people put an object of uncertain class in the variable and check it later, to save having to introduce another variable.

Comment: Maybe `string.length > 0` ?

Answer (score 6):

they are not the same, the `NSNull` is a valid object (inherited from `NSObject`) opposite a `nil` pointer, which points to nothing.

that is how you can check, whether an object is an `NSNull` object, but you first version is also okay.

```
id _object = // any kind of NSObject ...

if ([_object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
   // Logic handling
}
```

Comment: A check `== [NSNull null]` is perfectly valid, too.

Answer (score 0):

`nil` means nothing.
`[NSNull null]` is an object, instance of class `NSNull`
`==` means equality

`something equals to something else` is not the same as `something is equal to nothing`

Answer (score 0):

`[NSNull null]` returns the singleton instance of `NSNull`.

`aString == [NSNull null]` compares two pointers. As long as `aString` does not point to the `NSNull` singleton, they will never be equal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a string to nil:
 1. if(aString.length==0)
{
}
2.if(sString isEqualToString:@"")
{
}
3.if(aString!=nil)
{
} else
{
//do your stuff here
}

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSString*)replaceNullValuesWithEmptyString:(id)tempObj
{
if (([tempObj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])||
    (tempObj == nil) ||
    (tempObj == (id)[NSNull null])||
    [tempObj isEqual:[NSNull null]] ||
    [tempObj isEqual:nil]) {
}
else {
    if([tempObj respondsToSelector:@selector(isEqualToString:)]) {
        if ([tempObj isEqualToString:@"<null>"] ||
            [tempObj isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) {
        }
        else {
            if ([tempObj respondsToSelector:@selector(length)]) {
                if ([tempObj length]>0) {
                     NSLog(@"Check Passed.");
                    return tempObj;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
NSLog(@"Check failed.");
return @"";
```

}