# Unable to check constant value is null or not

Tags: ios, null, constants

i have  constant for language.At first time when  constant value null i want to set a specific value on this constant i write the given below code  but its not working correct :

```
  NSLog(@"Constant value:%@",[Constant getLangCode]);// this print null
  if([[Constant getLangCode] isEqualToString:null])  //this if is not working always goes else 
   {
    NSLog(@"null");
    [Constant updateLangCode:@"en"];
   }
 else
   {
   NSLog(@"null else");
    [Constant updateLangCode:@"en"];
   }
```

this gives following output:

```
       constant value:(null)
        null else
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684157/how-to-detect-if-nsstring-is-null/5684166#5684166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't work. Check whether the value is nil like this

```
  if([Constant getLangCode] == nil)
```

or in short

```
  if(![Constant getLangCode])
```

But even then your code doesn't make any sense because in both cases you call the same method with the same parameter. Why do you need the if statement?