# Error pulling NSDates from plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to pull NSDates from my plist, in order to create Datecomponents, but trying to do so give me problems.

This is some of the code I'm using:

```
self.Array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"matches" ofType:@"plist"]];

NSDateComponents *todayComp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDateComponents *eventDateComp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[Array valueForKey:@"date"]];
```

I'm getting the todayComp's correctly, but the eventDateComp's, which I'm trying to get frm the plist, gives an error.

The plist is an array of dictionaries, like this:

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <date>2011-12-13T00:00:00Z</date>
    <key>titel</key>
    <string>Tilburg - Oss</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <date>2011-12-13T00:00:00Z</date>
    <key>titel</key>
    <string>Amsterdam - Roosendaal</string>
</dict>
</array>
```

NSLog says something like this...

```
-[__NSArrayI timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a8d050
```

...which probably holds that I'm not getting the NSDates from the plist in the right way, but I have tried some different things, but have no clue how to do it right.
Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Array valueForKey:@"date"]
```

You are using valueforKey: method on NSArray.
1) use objectAtIndex: to get an object from array;
2) [Difference between objectForKey and valueForKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/objective-c-whats-the-difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey)

```
NSDate *eventDate = [[Array objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"date"];
NSDateComponents *eventDateComp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:eventDate];
```

Comment: Tried to implement the code and works, but it only gets the date from the first dictionary (due to objectAtIndex being 0). How can I go through all the dictionaries and thus get all the dates?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-BBCFABCB