# Get CoreData object data type based on input string

Tags: iphone, ios, string, core-data, object

Is it possible to detect object type from CoreData model based on input string?

My CoreData model "myEntity" has many objects of type NSStrings and NSNumbers, e.g. properties like "name", "lastName", etc.

In a query I want to determine object type (string or number) for let say "lastName" based on input string like that:

```
if ([myEntity.{lastName} isMemberOfClass:[NSString class]]) {}
```

Where `{lastName}` is dynamic text.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you meen something like this:

```
NSString* inputString = @"lastName";
if ([[myEntity valueForKey:inputString] isMemberOfClass:[NSString class]]) {}
```

If so just be carefull to validate the string.

Comment: No, [myEntity valueForKey:inputString] gets the actual value of an object and not the object itself. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Benjamin is correct. See this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/objective-c-whats-the-difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey

Comment: I don't think so. This only retrieves object value but not the object. I am aware of KVC coding but could not figure out this one - kind a reverse logic.

Comment: It returns an id so if all you want to do is check wether it is a NSString or a NSNumber that should be enough.

Comment: I just found out that this is solution indeed. Thanks!