# NSDictionary access values shortcut

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, nsdictionary

I don't understand the differences between these ways of accessing `NSDictionary` values

```
[my_dict objectForKey:@"field"]
[my_dict valueForKey:@"field"]
my_dict[@"field"]
```

Can someone tell me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/objective-c-whats-the-difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey

Comment: My primary interrogation was more about the `my_dict[@"field"]` shortcut.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`[my_dict objectForKey:@"field"]` is an `NSDictionary` method. It accepts any type of object.

`[my_dict valueForKey:@"field"]` is KVC method. It accepts only `NSString`.

`my_dict[@"field"]` is same as `objectForKey:`. This is new feature added.

Comment: Just seen this.  Take a look at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#dictionary-style-subscripting  for a full discussion on the subject of literals and subscripting.