# objectForKey VS valueForKey - difference between objectForKey and valueForKey

Tags: objective-c

Good morning friends 
I am new to IOS development and i want to know what is the difference between objectForKey and valueForKey. Who is the best in the way of performance? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. As you enter a question (before clicking on Submit), SO will show you related and possibly duplicate answers to your own. Please check these before submitting your new question. You aren't the first person to ask this.

Comment: Googled your title - [first link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey)

Answer (score 1):

`valueForKey` and `objectForKey` both will return the object for the given key. But here `valuForKey` is key-value coding.

If `key` does not start with “@”, invokes `objectForKey`:. If key does start with “@”, strips the “@” and invokes `[super valueForKey:]` with the rest of the key.

Comment: However, sometimes, there is a practical difference which I don't understand clearly yet. `valueForKey` didn't work in SOGo-3.1.4's code trying to call an unavailable "method" `ASProtocolVersion` on the `context` object (`EXCEPTION: <NSException: 0x55f43f93e4d0> NAME:NSInvalidArgumentException REASON:-[WOContext ASProtocolVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`), whereas `objectForKey` works (and is the usual way to query the `context` object elesewhere in the code). See https://github.com/inverse-inc/sogo/pull/217/files