# iOS SDK: MapKit MKPolyLine not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, mapkit

I'm trying to display a polyline on my map, but the line doesn't show up. I tried a lot of things, but noting seems to work.

I checked the Core Data functions, and it is returning data, so that is not the problem. It must me somewhere in the mappoint creation or the dwawing on the map (I guess).
I'm sure it must be a little mistake somewhere, but I can't find it.

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    mapView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)createLine
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Logs" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *logs = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    int logsCount = [logs count];
    MKMapPoint points[logsCount];

    // loop logs
    for (int i = 0; i < logsCount; i++)
    {
        MKMapPoint point;
        point = MKMapPointMake([[[logs objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[[logs objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]);

        points[i] = point;
    }

    MKPolyline *routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:points count:logsCount];
    [mapView addOverlay:routeLine];
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKOverlayView *mapOverlayView = [[MKOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    return mapOverlayView;
}
```

Comment: What does your `mapView:viewForOverlay:` method look like?

Comment: Also note the code is assigning a lat/long to an MKMapPoint.  An MKMapPoint is _not_ a latitude/longitude.  Use CLLocationCoordinate2D instead of MKMapPoint, CLLocationCoordinate2DMake instead of MKMapPointMake and polylineWithCoordinates instead of polylineWithPoints.

Comment: I changed it to MKMapPoint because i thought that that was the problem. I'll set it back to CLLocationCoordinate2D.
I also added my mapView:viewForOverlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with the code shown:

1. The polyline is being created using `MKMapPoint`s which are incorrectly set to latitude/longitude values.  An `MKMapPoint` is not degrees of latitude/longitude.  It is an x/y transformation of a lat/long on the flat map projection.  Either *convert* the latitude/longitude values to `MKMapPoint`s using `MKMapPointForCoordinate` or just use `CLLocationCoordinate2D` instead.  Just using `CLLocationCoordinate2D` when you have the lat/long is much easier to code and understand.
2. In `viewForOverlay`, the code is creating an empty `MKOverlayView` which is invisible.  Create an `MKPolylineView` instead (a subclass of `MKOverlayView` that draws `MKPolyline`s) and set its `strokeColor`.

For the first issue, use:

- `CLLocationCoordinate2D` instead of `MKMapPoint`,
- `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` instead of `MKMapPointMake`,
- and `polylineWithCoordinates` instead of `polylineWithPoints`

For the second issue, here's an example:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineView *mapOverlayView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
        //add autorelease if not using ARC
        mapOverlayView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        mapOverlayView.lineWidth = 2;
        return mapOverlayView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

A couple of other things:

- Instead of `valueForKey:@"lat"`, I would use `objectForKey:@"lat"` (same for `@"lng"`).
- Make sure the map view's `delegate` is set otherwise the `viewForOverlay` delegate method will not get called even with all the other changes.

Comment: Thank you for the very extensive answer! It is working now :-)

One note: the objectForKey:@"" is not working (got an error saying there is no such selector on the object), so I'm using valueForKey:@"". Why should one use objectForKey instead of valueForKey?

Comment: I thought you were calling it on an NSDictionary.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey.