# MKMapPointForCoordinate returning invalid coordinates

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I am working with MKMapView's, annotations, overlays, etc, but I'm having a pain in the butt issue with MKMapPointForCoordinate() returning an invalid coordinate.

Code:

```
MKMapPoint* pointArr;
for (Category* route in validRoutes){

    NSString* routeID = [route routeid];
    NSArray* pointData = [routes objectForKey:routeID];

    pointArr = malloc(sizeof(MKMapPoint) * [pointData count]);
    int i = 0;

    for (NSDictionary* routeData in pointData) {

        NSString* latitude = [routeData objectForKey:@"latitude"];
        NSString* longitude = [routeData objectForKey:@"longitude"];
        NSLog(@"L: %@ L: %@",latitude, longitude);

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[f numberFromString:latitude] doubleValue], [[f numberFromString:longitude] doubleValue]);


        NSLog(@"Coord: %f %f",coord.latitude,coord.longitude);

        MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord);
        NSLog(@"Point: %f %f",point.x,point.y);
        pointArr[i] = point;
        i++;

    }

    MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count: i];
    polyline.title = [route name];
    [routeOverlays setObject:polyline forKey: [route routeid]];
    [map addOverlay:polyline];
    free(pointArr);
}
```

Output Example:

L: 41.380840 L: -83.641319

Coord: 41.380840 -83.641319

Point: 71850240.204982 100266073.824832

I don't understand why the conversion to a MKMapPoint is destroying the values of my CLLocationCoordinate2D. The overlay doesn't show up on the map because the values are invalid...

EDIT: I got the point working by using MKMapPointMake instead, BUT, my overlay still isn't showing. This is the mapView: viewForOverlay: code:

```
-(MKOverlayView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
MKOverlayView *overlayView = nil;

//Checks if the overlay is of type MKPolyline
if([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]){
    MKPolylineView *routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];

    routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    routeLineView.lineWidth = 10;
    return overlayView;
}

return nil;
}
```

The method gets called (Used a breakpoint to confirm), and I have annotations working (So the delegate has to be setup correctly, I assume)

Double edit: :facepalm: I was returning nil every time in the delegate code. That's what I get for copying and pasting the previous versions code ;P

Comment: I managed to get the MKMapPoint to work by using MKMapPointMake(x,y) with the coord.latitude and coord.longitude, but it is still not showing up on the map. =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `MKMapPoint` is ***not*** a latitude/longitude in degrees (like `CLLocationCoordinate2D`).

They are not interchangeable and so you should not expect the `MKMapPoint` x,y values to show any obvious relation to the corresponding latitude and longitude.

An `MKMapPoint` is the conversion of latitude and longitude onto a flat projection using x,y values which are not in the same scale or range as latitude and longitude.  Please see the [Map Coordinate Systems](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW6) section in the Location Awareness Programming Guide for a more detailed explanation.

By the way, if you have `CLLocationCoordinate2D` values, it's much easier to create a polyline using `polylineWithCoordinates` instead of `polylineWithPoints`.  That way, you don't need to bother with any conversion.

See [iOS SDK: MapKit MKPolyLine not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838360/ios-sdk-mapkit-mkpolyline-not-showing) for some more details and an example.

Comment: Thanks! I had a lot of other issues which ended up being the real problems ;O You can't add an overlay while not on the main thread