# MKOverlayRenderer not rendering

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay, mkpolygon

I'm having trouble getting an MKPolygonRenderer to appear over my map. I have a class `MapViewController` that contains an `MKMapView`, and create `CustomMapOverlay` instances to render over the `MKMapView`.

**MapViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}

// ...

// Later, I retrieve some models and generate CustomMapOverlay instances from them...
for (Model *model in models) {
    CustomMapOverlay *customMapOverlay = [[CustomMapOverlay alloc] initWithModel:model];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:customMapOverlay];
}

// ...

// Implement MKMapViewDelegate protocol
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    MKPolygonRenderer *polygonRenderer = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    polygonRenderer.lineWidth = 2;
    polygonRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.5 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    polygonRenderer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.5 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5];
    return polygonRenderer;
}
```

**CustomMapOverlay.m:**

```
@implementation CustomMapOverlay

// Required by MKOverlay protocol
@synthesize coordinate,
    boundingMapRect;

- (instancetype)initWithModel:(Model *)model {
    coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(model.latitude, model.longitude);
    double radiusInPoints = MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(model.latitude) * model.radius;
    boundingMapRect = MKMapRectMake(model.latitude, model.longitude, radiusInPoints, radiusInPoints);
    return self;
}

@end
```

`mapView:rendererForOverlay` is getting called, and inspecting the `overlay` in the debugger I see a `coordinate` within the map's current on-screen bounds and what seems like a reasonable `boundingMapRect` (though I'm not sure what "map points" are, I'm trusting that `MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude` method to do what it says it does).

But, no polygons appear on the map.

---

**UPDATE:**

I realize now that I'm attempting to render polygons without creating them. Instead of `CustomMapOverlay`, then, I'm now generating `MKPolygon` overlays like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(model.latitude, model.longitude);
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centerCoordinate, model.radius, model.radius);

int numCoords = 4;
CLLocationCoordinate2D *coords = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * numCoords);
coords[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((region.center.longitude - 0.5*region.span.longitudeDelta), (region.center.latitude + 0.5*region.span.latitudeDelta));
coords[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((region.center.longitude + 0.5*region.span.longitudeDelta), (region.center.latitude + 0.5*region.span.latitudeDelta));
coords[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((region.center.longitude + 0.5*region.span.longitudeDelta), (region.center.latitude - 0.5*region.span.latitudeDelta));
coords[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((region.center.longitude - 0.5*region.span.longitudeDelta), (region.center.latitude - 0.5*region.span.latitudeDelta));
MKPolygon *polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coords count:numCoords];
free(coords);

[self.mapView addOverlay:polygon];
```

However, now `mapView:rendererForOverlay` is no longer getting called at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the updated code which creates an `MKPolygon`, the coordinates in the `coords` array are backwards.  For example, this line:

```
coords[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
              (region.center.longitude - 0.5*region.span.longitudeDelta), 
              (region.center.latitude + 0.5*region.span.latitudeDelta));
```

should be:

```
coords[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
              (region.center.latitude + 0.5*region.span.latitudeDelta,
              (region.center.longitude - 0.5*region.span.longitudeDelta));
```

In the `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` function, the first parameter is *latitude*, then *longitude*.

Because the coordinates are backwards, they may either be completely invalid or in the wrong location.

The `rendererForOverlay` delegate method will only get called if the overlay's `boundingMapRect` (which `MKPolygon` will automatically define based on the given coordinates) is in the currently displayed area of the map.  But if the coordinates are invalid or in the wrong location, the `boundingMapRect` will be invalid as well.

---

By the way, in the original code which used `CustomMapOverlay`, there were at least these two issues:

1. The `initWithModel` method doesn't call `[super init]` (assuming it's an `NSObject` subclass).
2. The `boundingMapRect` is not calculated correctly.  The `MKMapRectMake` function takes `MKMapPoint` values but the code is passing latitude and longitude in degrees.  An `MKMapPoint` is not the same as a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.  You can convert a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to an `MKMapPoint` using the `MKMapPointForCoordinate` function.  See [MKMapPointForCoordinate returning invalid coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240343/mkmappointforcoordinate-returning-invalid-coordinates) and [Map Coordinate Systems in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html) for some more info.

Comment: I must have been very tired to make that lon-lat mistake. Also good to know about the purpose of boundingMapRect.