# NSMutableArray addObject getting set to nil after release of object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have declared an `NSMutableArray *arrAllRecordsM` and am trying to add `NSMutableDictionary *dicRecordM` to it using `addObject`. The `dicRecordM` gets added to `arrAllRecordsM` but on doing `[dicRecordM removeAllObjects]` it sets to nil in `arrAllRecordsM`. Below is the code, please help me fix it.

```
self.arrAllRecordsM = [NSMutableArray array];
self.dicRecordM = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

// Some Method

```
[self.dicRecordM setObject:@"Test" forKey:@"ADDRESS"];
[self.arrAllRecordsM addObject:self.dicRecordM];

// Value: Test
NSLog(@"Value: %@", [[self.arrAllRecordsM objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"ADDRESS"]);
[self.dicRecordM removeAllObjects];

// Value: null
NSLog(@"Value: %@", [[self.arrAllRecordsM objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"ADDRESS"]);
```

Comment: Your code is behaving correctly. Why do you expect a different result? You are trying to obtain a nonexistent value. Of course it's going to return `nil`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding an object to an `NSMutableArray` just stores a *pointer* (or "strong reference")
to the object into the array. Therefore

```
[self.arrAllRecordsM objectAtIndex:0]
```

and

```
self.dicRecordM
```

are two pointers to the **same object**. If your remove all key/value pairs from `self.dicRecordM` then `[self.arrAllRecordsM objectAtIndex:0]` still points to the same
(now empty) dictionary. That is the reason why

```
[[self.arrAllRecordsM objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"ADDRESS"]
```

returns `nil`.

If you want an independent copy of the dictionary in the array, use

```
[self.arrAllRecordsM addObject:[self.dicRecordM copy]];
```

`copy` can be used on many classes, such as `NSDictionary`, `NSArray` and `NSString` 
and their mutable variants, to get a "functionally independent object". Formally, it is available for all classes conforming to the `NSCopying` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior.
You removed all the objects from the dictionary by calling `removeAllObjects`, then tried to retrieve an object from it and rightfully getting `nil`, since it doesn't exist in the dictionay anymore (you removed it).

What's maybe unclear to you is that `NSArray` doesn't copy the element you add to it, instead it just holds a strong reference.

So both `dicRecordM` and `arrAllRecordsM` are holding a reference to the **same** object, hence any modification to it (in this case `removeAllObjects`) will affect the same dictionary.

---

Incidentally, you shouldn't use `valueForKey:` for accessing the dictionary's entries. Use `objectForKey:` or the shorter subscripted syntax. For instance

```
self.arrAllRecordsM[0][@"ADDRESS"]
```

You can read this answer [Difference between objectForKey and valueForKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey) as a reference, but the main problem is that `valueForKey:` can behave very differently from `objectForKey:` in case the key contains special KVC characters, such as `@` or `.`.