# Create and sort array of dictionaries from previous array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary

I really tried not to ask the question here but after hours of trying, I'm stuck.  So here goes... hopefully I can be clear.

My desired output is this:

```
({
    following = "";
    followingMe = "";
},{
    following = "";
    followingMe = "";
},{...})
```

The data coming in looks like this and what I want to do is sort it

```
({
    user = "me";
    following = "sam";
},{
    user = "sam";
    following = "me";
},{
    user = "foo";
    following = "me";
},{
    user = "me";
    following = "bar";
},...)
```

I want to organize it so if I'm following "sam" and he's following me, it's one dictionary.  If "foo" is following me, then `following="(null)`" and `followingMe="sam"`...and so on.  That's why I didn't want to ask the question... it's hard to explain.

Here's the code I have but it just gives me the last entry over and over...what's the typo?

```
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
int i = 0;
while (i < array.count) {
    [temp removeAllObjects];
    if ([[[array objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"user"]isEqualToString:_user]){
    //means I'm following this person
        [temp setValue:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"following"] forKey:@"following"];

        if ([[_allfriends valueForKey:@"followingMe"]containsObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"following"]]) {
        //check to see if this person is already following me

            [[_allfriends objectAtIndex:[[_allfriends valueForKey:@"followingMe"] indexOfObject:
            [[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"following"]]] setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"following"] forKey:@"following"];
            //trying to update at the index where this person is following me

        }else{
            [temp setObject:@"(null)" forKey:@"followingMe"];
            [_allfriends addObject:temp];
        }
    }else{
        //this person is following me
        [temp setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"user"] forKey:@"followingMe"];

        if ([[_allfriends valueForKey:@"following"]containsObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"user"]]) {
        //check to see if I'm following this pseron

            [[_allfriends objectAtIndex:[[_allfriends valueForKey:@"following"] indexOfObject:
            [[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"user"]]] setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"user"] forKey:@"followingMe"];
            //try to update followingMe at that index

        }else{
            [temp setObject:@"(null)" forKey:@"following"];
            [_allfriends addObject:temp];
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

So the logic is I'm checking where my name is (`user` or `following`).  Then I'm checking if the person is already `followingMe`.  It it's an entry in the `_allfriends`, I need to get that index and I want to update the "`following`"...makes sense?  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

U can sort array with Set

```
SortedArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSSet setWithArray: UnsortedArr] allObjects]];
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that should help me but it just gave me the original array right back

Comment: sorry, but this will remove duplicate element from an array...not  sorting

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the problem was with the `NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];`.  I'm not sure if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177836/nsmutablearray-addobject-getting-set-to-nil-after-release-of-object) applies but it made me rewrite my code.  temp values were attached to the `_allfriends` array so when temp changed, EVERYTHING in `_allfriends` changed.  My loop logic was correct but I rewrote it like this:

```
NSString *key = [NSString new];
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
    if ([[[array objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"user"]isEqualToString:_user]){
        key = [[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"following"];
        if ([[_allfriends valueForKey:@"followingMe"]containsObject:key]) {
            [_allfriends removeObjectAtIndex:[[_allfriends valueForKey:@"followingMe"] indexOfObject:key]];
            [_allfriends insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:key, @"following", key, @"followingMe", nil] atIndex:_allfriends.count];
        }else{
            [_allfriends insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:key, @"following", @"(null)", @"followingMe", nil] atIndex:_allfriends.count];
        }
    }else{
        key = [[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"user"];
        if ([[_allfriends valueForKey:@"following"]containsObject:key]) {
            [_allfriends removeObjectAtIndex:[[_allfriends valueForKey:@"following"] indexOfObject:key]];
            [_allfriends insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:key, @"following", key, @"followingMe", nil] atIndex:_allfriends.count];
        }else{
            [_allfriends insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:key, @"followingMe", @"(null)", @"following", nil] atIndex:_allfriends.count];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps someone...