# Having trouble parsing more complex JSON in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

Part of my app gets `JSON` data and uses it to display updates.  There's two parts to the initial `JSON` response: an error and an update section.

The following is the array you get when doing `[JSONData objectForKey:@"updates"];` to isolate the update section

```
{
2 =     {
    message = "Best restaurant ever!";
    name = " ";
    profilePictureURL = "<null>";
    restPictureURL = "http://i.imgur.com/QpyMRwY.jpg";
    restaurant = "someplace";
    timestamp = 1390194000;
};
3 =     {
    message = "Ehh.";
    name = " ";
    profilePictureURL = "<null>";
    restPictureURL = "http://i.imgur.com/QpyMRwY.jpg";
    restaurant = "someplace";
    timestamp = 1389848400;
};
4 =     {
    message = "";
    name = " ";
    profilePictureURL = "<null>";
    restPictureURL = "http://i.imgur.com/QpyMRwY.jpg";
    restaurant = "McDonald's";
    timestamp = 1390346335;
};
5 =     {
    message = "Service was slow.";
    name = " ";
    profilePictureURL = "<null>";
    restPictureURL = "http://i.imgur.com/QpyMRwY.jpg";
    restaurant = "Bad pizzaplace";
    timestamp = 1389330000;
};
}
```

Then I pass this `NSArray` to a function which formats it to a class I designed for updates and then appends that update to a `NSMutableArray` stored in `AppDelegate`.

```
@implementation Update
+(void) appendUpdates:(NSArray*)data
{


    AppDelegate* appDelegate=  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    for (NSDictionary* currentUpdate in data)
    {
        Update* formattedUpdate = [[Update alloc]initWithDict:currentUpdate];
        [appDelegate.updateList addObject:formattedUpdate];
    }

}
-(id) initWithDict:(NSDictionary*)update
{
    self = [super init];
    self.name = [update objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.restaurant = [update objectForKey:@"restaurant"];
    self.message = [update objectForKey:@"message"];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(int)[update objectForKey:@"timestamp"]];
    self.timestamp = date;
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    self.dateComponents = components;
    self.profilePictureURL = [update objectForKey:@"profilePictureURL"];
    self.restaurantPictureURL = [update objectForKey:@"restPictureURL"];
    return self;
}

@end
```

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0Q7hbmrN)

When I run the code, I receive an error inside the initialization method when trying to use `objectForKey:`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error says?

Comment: `-[__NSCFString allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9bc5380
2014-01-21 23:55:25.938 MyApp[49350:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9bc5380'`

Comment: @JasonMarmon : Have a look at the JSON format. In My answer.

Comment: What trouble did you have when formatting the code? it is easy: paste it in, select the code, hit the source code button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean solution is to just create a dictionary object inside your `Update` class & then add your keyValues & return that dictionary. Also keep in mind what you want to use to access values from dictionary `valueForKey` or `objectForKey`. They both have difference. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1062573/1307844) in short.

**May be you can format your JSON file**

```
{
"updates":
 [
   {
     "ID":1,
     "SystemCovered":"Dept/State Outage Reporting",
     "InchargeFirstName":"Davids",
   },
    {
      "ID":2,
      "SystemCovered":"State Outage Reporting",
      "InchargeFirstName":"Davids-123",
   },
    {
      "ID":2,
      "SystemCovered":"Reporting",
      "InchargeFirstName":"Davids-234",
    }
 ]
}
```

**A THUMB RULE**

While parsing JSON, Whenever you encounter `[ ]`, treat it as an `Array` & whenever you see '{ }', treat is at `dictionary`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I can't imagine why I would need to subclass from NSDictionary.  Returning an instance of `self` when the method is inside of class `Update` should return an Update object, which is what an init method should do.

I think the error is incorrectly formatted JSON, so I'll talk to my backend person tomorrow to get it fixed

Comment: You may be correct, I am not denying as I was not knowing what error you got. Now I can see, you have posted the exception.

Comment: Yep.  I figured out the JSON problem right when you did.  Because I can't change what happens on the server side, I got the array members using "objectForKey:@"1...2...3..."" But this is definitely the best answer for anyone else that stumbles upon this.

Comment: Ok, Adding one thumb Rule also: 
Whenever you encounter `[ ]`, treat it as an `Array` & when you see `{ }`, treat is at `dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Change your `appendUpdates:` method to

```
+(void) appendUpdates:(NSArray*)data
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate=  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    for (NSDictionary* currentUpdate in data)
    {
        NSString *key = [[currentUpdate allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];
        currentUpdate = [currentUpdate objectForKey:key];
        Update* formattedUpdate = [[Update alloc]initWithDict:currentUpdate];
        [appDelegate.updateList addObject:formattedUpdate];
    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't work =/  I think it has to do with the beginning and trailing brackets on the JSON data, but I'm not sure how to remove them

Answer (score 0):

Change your method as `+(void) appendUpdates:(NSDictionary*)data` instead `+(void) appendUpdates:(NSArray*)data`. Because you have Dictionary(not an array) which contains dictionary of object.

And your method definition should be..

```
+(void) appendUpdates:(NSDictionary*)data
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate=  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    for (NSString* key in [data allKeys])
    {
        NSDictionary *currentUpdate = [data objectForKey:key];
        Update* formattedUpdate = [[Update alloc]initWithDict:currentUpdate];
        [appDelegate.updateList addObject:formattedUpdate];
    }

}
```