# Strange keys in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I am trying to sort a `uitableview` alphabetically and also with sections. Therefore I use this function

```
-(void)updateName{
    sectionsNaam = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; ///Global Object

        BOOL found;

        for (Relation *tempRelation in resultsRelations)
        {
            NSString *c;
            if(tempRelation.rel_name.length == 0){
                continue;
            }else{
                c =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[tempRelation.rel_name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];

            }

            found = NO;

            for (NSString *str in [sectionsNaam allKeys])
            {
                if ([str isEqualToString:c])
                {
                    found = YES;
                }
            }
            NSLog(@"STRIG IS %@",c);

            if (!found)
            {
                [sectionsNaam setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
            }
        }
        for (Relation *tempRelation in resultsRelations)
        {
            if(tempRelation.rel_name.length == 0){
                continue;
            }else{
                [[sectionsNaam objectForKey:[[tempRelation.rel_name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]] addObject:tempRelation];
            }
        }
    NSLog(@"SECTIONS NAAM IS %@",[sectionsNaam allKeys]);


    _typeView = 100;
    [tableRelations reloadData];
}
```

When I log all the first letters I noticed these ones:

```
2014-12-04 10:06:49.674 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS '
2014-12-04 10:06:49.674 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS  
2014-12-04 10:06:49.674 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS  
2014-12-04 10:06:49.674 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS "
2014-12-04 10:06:49.674 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS &
2014-12-04 10:06:49.674 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS (
2014-12-04 10:06:49.674 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS (
2014-12-04 10:06:49.674 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS (
2014-12-04 10:06:49.675 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS (
2014-12-04 10:06:49.675 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS @
2014-12-04 10:06:49.675 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS @
2014-12-04 10:06:49.675 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS @
2014-12-04 10:06:49.675 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS \
2014-12-04 10:06:49.675 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS ´
2014-12-04 10:06:49.675 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS “
2014-12-04 10:06:49.675 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS “
2014-12-04 10:06:49.675 Adsolut[43298:8578408] STRIG IS £
```

And then when I log the keys of the NSDictionary I see this:

```
SECTIONS NAAM IS (
    3,
    K,
    4,
    L,
    5,
    M,
    N,
    "\U00dc",
    "\U201c",
    7,
    " ",
    8,
    O,
    P,
    "\U00c7",
    Q,
    "\"",
    R,
    "\U00c9",
    S,
    T,
    U,
    "&",
    "\U00b4",
    V,
    "'",
    W,
    "(",
    "@",
    X,
    A,
    Y,
    B,
    Z,
    C,
    D,
    "\\",
    "\U00a3",
    E,
    F,
    "\U00d4",
    G,
    H,
    "\U00d6",
    1,
    I,
    2,
    J
)
```

Now when I reload my table the app crashes on this line

```
 rows = [[sectionsNaam valueForKey:[[[sectionsNaam allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
```

With this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryM 0x7fa7a34c8f40> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key .'
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between `valueForKey` and `objectForKey`.

`valueForKey` is a KVC method for any object to find a property with the name you have passed in.

`objectForKey` is a dictionary method to find an object inside the dictionary with the string as its key pair.

more info: [Difference between objectForKey and valueForKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey)

You should be using `objectForKey` where your code is crashing. `objectForKey` can return `nil` if its not found. `valueForKey` requires that the key be present in the class ... or else crash.

Comment: @StefGeelen no prob, glad it helped