# How do I use dictionary literal syntax without subclassing from NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsdictionary

I don't want to subclass from `NSDictionary` but I want to get the literal syntax. It means that I am about to save and retrieve the key by using the "[]". I get this question from **Parse** iOS SDK, the `PFObject` is not inherited from the `NSMutableDictionary`. And they are able to use the dictionary literal syntax.

Here is the link from Parse iOS SDK: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects/iOS.

Comment: Do you mean using id *var = dict[@"key"] instead of id *var = [dict valueForKey:@"key"] and dict[@"key"] = var instead of [dict setValue:var forKey:@"key"]?

Comment: @VictorIppolitov: Beware! [The `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:` methods should **not** be used to access a dictionary!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey). Use `objectForKey:` and `setObject:forKey:` instead.

Comment: @DarkDust Thank you. I will keep in mind it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See for example the good [*Object Subscripting* article at *NSHipster*](http://nshipster.com/object-subscripting/). You just need to implement two methods in your class:

```
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key;
- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key;
```