# iOS Swift Error: Execution was interrupted, reason : signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to execute the following code in a playground. Fairly, I am treating both variables `bm` and `ul` equally but error shows only at `ul`

```
import UIKit

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject([], forKey: "bookmarks")
defaults.setObject([], forKey: "urls")

var bm : NSMutableArray = defaults.valueForKey("bookmarks") as NSMutableArray
var ul : NSMutableArray = defaults.valueForKey("urls") as NSMutableArray

bm.addObject("Google")                 //--->Works
ul.addObject("http://google.com")      //--->Oops, No
```

Comment: That just blew my mind. ;)

Comment: This really is odd. Here's the error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell you why the first works and the second doesn't - it is probably just a quirk of playgrounds, timing and a delay in persisting NSUserDefaults to disk.

Your problem, however, is that `valueForKey` (and you should use [`objectForKey`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey)) returns immutable objects - so `bm` and `ul` will actually be `NSArray` instances and you can't simply cast them to `NSMutableArray`. You get a crash when you try to do so and mutate the object.

You need to create a mutable copy of your array.

```
 var bm=defaults.objectForKey("bookmarks") as NSArray?

 if bm != nil {
    var bmCopy=bm!.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    bmCopy.addObject("Google")
    defaults.setObject(bmCopy, forKey:"bookmarks")
 }
```