# Populating a UITableView cell iOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm having a hair pulling problem in a UITableView. I'm just trying to pick out a name field from an array. I must be doing something dumb, but I can't see it. Any ideas please..

```
NSMutableArray *localStop = [localArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"localStop: %@", localStop);


BOTH OF THESE RETURN NULL

cell.nameLabel.text = [[localArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name" ];

OR

cell.nameLabel.text = [localStop valueForKey:@"Name"];


    NSLog(@"localStop Name1: %@", cell.nameLabel.text);
    NSLog(@"localStop Name2: %@", [[localArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"]);
```

HOWEVER THE LATTER SHOWS NULL IN THE CELL, BUT DISPLAYS CORRECTLY IN THE CONSOLE.

```
CONSOLE OUTPUT:

 localStop: {
    Lat = "38.928922";
    Lon = "-77.037531";
    Name = "MT PLEASANT ST NW + IRVING ST NW";
    Routes =     (
        42,
        43
    );
    StopID = 1002005;
}


localStop Name1: (null)
localStop Name2: MT PLEASANT ST NW + IRVING ST NW
```

Comment: Your output "localStop: {...}" indicates that localStop is a dictionary. However, you are initializing it as an NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1):

You declared

```
NSMutableArray *localStop
```

as an array and when you call `valueForKey` on an array it should return an `NSArray`. Not a `NSString`. (is `localArray` a two-dimensional array??)

I think you should declare `localStop` as `NSMutableDictionary`
But of course I am not totally sure if this is the case since I don't know what kind of data is contained inside `localArray`.

However, if `localArray` is a `NSDictionary` Array then I don't know why this returns NULL:

```
cell.nameLabel.text = [[localArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
```

If `localArray` is a two-dimensional array then it's obvious why there is a problem. You are trying to set a `UILabel`s text attribute which is a `NSString` with a `NSArray` (still you should not see NULL but the content of the array as a string) I am confused too:)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably lies in `valueForKey:` when you take data out of the array.

You need to tell us/know/act according to the type of data inside the array.

Usually you'd have custom objects when it comes to cell-filling arrays, so our first example would be custom objects that have properties you display, say

We have a Student objet, that has a name and an age for example, and you'd just have :

```
Student *currentStudent = [localArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.nameLabel.text = currentStudent.name;
cell.ageLabel.text  = currentStudent.age.stringValue;
```

If you have an `NSDictionary` in your array, then it's pretty much the same, except that you extract an `NSDictionary` out of the array and use the `-objetForKey:` method to retrieve the different keys you need.

Make sure to note [the difference between objectForKey and valueForKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey)

You could also skip the part where you create an object from the array and straight up reference the strings from the array, like so

for the student example :

```
cell.nameLabel.text = [[localArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];
```

or the dictionary :

```
cell.nameLabel.text = [[localArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Reworking your code following these instructions should solve your problem. If it doesn't, please provide more information about what is in the array and comment here to notify me :)

After looking at the `NSLog`, it really appears that you have an array of dictionaries (which is fine), so you have to adapt your code using `objectForKey` and treating what's in your array as an `NSDictionary` and definitly not as an `NSMutablArray`, as suggested by NSWill (in the comments)

Comment: Many thanks to both of you. It turned out to be a problem with naming a custom cell class. I forgot that I was calling a custom cell. But you both gave me ideas to take a fresh look, and I  appreciate that.

Comment: Good that you fixed your issue ;)