# UITableVIew didSelectRowAtIndexPath inside VIewController not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I added this code to my ViewController class under (#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate Methods)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"selected cell = %@", cell.textLabel.text);

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    NSLog(@"row = %ld", indexPath.row);
}
```

I just want to display the text that I select but it's not working. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Full code is here: [IOS 8 Objective-C Search bar and Table view Using Google Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370632/ios-8-objective-c-search-bar-and-table-view-using-google-autocomplete)

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:
I also added the following code:

viewDidLoad method (ViewController.m)

```
_tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.dataSource = self;
```

changed ViewController.h code from

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

to

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Comment: have you set delegates?

Comment: yes. I forgot to mention I did this already. >.<

Comment: are your cells user interaction enabled?

Comment: What is not working ? The method is not called ? It's not doing what you were expecting ?
Can you show `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: I only allowed selection during editing because I read that from the forums. how do I set user interaction?

Comment: please try debugging  and check if control enters 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath` by setting a break point. so that we could know better

Comment: It doesn't seem to be entering the 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' at all. >.<

Comment: as you said you are allowing selection only on editing so i think the method you need to check is `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I tried willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath and willSelectRowAtIndexPath. It doesn't seem to be responding to any UITableViewDelegate Methods >.<

Comment: Did you connect the tableView property with a table view object in Interface builder?

Answer (score 1):

in viewDidLoad set the delegates

```
_table.delegate = self;
_table.dataSource = self;
```

in the interface then declare the protocols

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Comment: You can also se the the delegates by ctrl-dragging from table view to view controller on storyboard.

Comment: I forgot to mention I did this already. I'm sorry for that >.< But, I think I'm still missing something because it's still not showing after I did this >.<

Answer (score 1):

`[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:]`... only works when wrapped inbetween `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]`;

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

check if the delegate is set to `self`

```
_tableView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger and break points.
I would put a break point in:

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

and see if the program stops there or not.

Comment: Thanks for this! It doesn't seem to stop there. I tried to NSLog random text just to see if it entered the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method during selection, but it didn't output anything.

Comment: In that case you know the problem is with connections, that is, delegates. Specifically UITableViewDelegate (not UITableViewDataSource)

Comment: That does seem to be the problem. The UITableViewDataSource Methods work just fine, but it won't enter any of the UITableViewDelegate Methods

Comment: Nice, if you mark my response as correct, it would be even better :)
BTW I suggest you use interface builder to make these connections from the view (tableview) to your controller (tableviewcontroller).

Comment: But the problem's not fixed yet?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the method is not enough. You should set your 'delegate' property of table view to the 'self' where 'self' means your view controller.

For example in your .m file:

```
@interface MyViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
}

...

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
}
```

EDIT: Also please make sure you have connected the `tableView` property with a table view object inside of Interface Builder.

Comment: Does this have a different effect from _tableView.delegate = self? I'll try this out. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it does the same, but accesses to the table view via getter.

Comment: It's still not accessing the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method >.<

Comment: Did you have any records in the table? How many rows are returned from tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set this properties in Interface Builder?

[image: Interface Builder]

Answer (score 0):

Method name changed or wrong. You can drag-drop to set the ViewController as the delegate. But this method needed to process when row touched:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("section: \(indexPath.section)")
    print("row: \(indexPath.row)")
    // caller is set to the calling ViewController, when it "prepare" to launch this one
    caller.payFromSelection( selectedIndex: indexPath.row )
}
```

Back in the main controller, it gets the value and closes the child vc having the tableview...

```
func payFromSelection( selectedIndex:Int ) -> Void {
    print( selectedIndex )
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    //self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```