# Objective C - Parse json array

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

I want to parse parseItems but I don't know how

```
json = [
  {
    "devicename" : "WL-00000003",
    "activated" : "true",
    "displayname" : "wit003 ",
    "portitems" : {
      "port1" : "Smoke Sensor",
      "port4" : "",
      "port3" : "",
      "port6" : "Alarm Siren",
      "port2" : "",
      "port5" : ""
    },
    "accountType" : "admin",
    "deviceaddress" : "",
    "devicestatus" : ""
  }
]
```

It would be easy if portItems would be in this format `"portitems" : ({ })`

I tried it using this code but it gets error.

```
NSDictionary *fetchedDictionaryresult = [json objectForKey:@"portItems"];
    for (NSDictionary *event in  fetchedDictionaryresult)
    {
        _strPart1 = [event objectForKey:@"port1"];
        _strPart2 = [event objectForKey:@"port2"];
        _strPart3 = [event objectForKey:@"port3"];
        _strPart4 = [event objectForKey:@"port4"];
        _strPart5 = [event objectForKey:@"port5"];
        _strPart6 = [event objectForKey:@"port6"];
    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: it's json Dictionary

Comment: `portitems` != `portItems`. C / Objective-C is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for getting `portItems` you did not need for loop just directly use your dictionary `fetchedDictionaryresult` like this:

Also I guess you got array not dictionary in `Json`

**Try this:**

```
NSDictionary *fetchedDictionaryresult = [json[0] objectForKey:@"portItems"];

 _strPart1 = [fetchedDictionaryresult objectForKey:@"port1"];
 _strPart2 = [fetchedDictionaryresult objectForKey:@"port2"];
 _strPart3 = [fetchedDictionaryresult objectForKey:@"port3"];
 _strPart4 = [fetchedDictionaryresult objectForKey:@"port4"];
 _strPart5 = [fetchedDictionaryresult objectForKey:@"port5"];
 _strPart6 = [fetchedDictionaryresult objectForKey:@"port6"];
```

Comment: But it get's this error `-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Check my updated answer i guess you are getting Array in `json` not NSDictionary.

Comment: Nope, because it becomes (null) after i made json[0] but it did return NSString. I have to make adjustments.

Comment: means you didn't get `_strPart1` value ?

Comment: It gets error when I try to directly get row [0] from `[json[0] objectForKey:@"portItems"];` because json is NSDictionary that's why I made this base on your answer with row [0]
`id event = [json valueForKey:@"portitems"];`
`_strPart1 = [event[0] valueForKey:@"port1"];`

Comment: Thanks & appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
Here the json is first getting parsed into a dictionary and then we are getting the "portitems" dictionary and then getting strings out of it.

```
- (void)setPartStringsFrom:(NSData *)json
{
    NSError *localError = nil;
    NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:0 error:&localError];

    if (localError == nil) {
        NSDictionary *event = [parsedObject[0] valueForKey:@"portitems"];

        _strPart1 = [event valueForKey:@"port1"];
        _strPart2 = [event valueForKey:@"port2"];
        _strPart3 = [event valueForKey:@"port3"];
        _strPart4 = [event valueForKey:@"port4"];
        _strPart5 = [event valueForKey:@"port5"];
        _strPart6 = [event valueForKey:@"port6"];

    }
}
```

and if `json` is already a dictionary then

```
 - (void)setPartStringsFrom:(NSDictionary *)json
{
    NSDictionary *event = [json[0] valueForKey:@"portitems"];

    _strPart1 = [event valueForKey:@"port1"];
    _strPart2 = [event valueForKey:@"port2"];
    _strPart3 = [event valueForKey:@"port3"];
    _strPart4 = [event valueForKey:@"port4"];
    _strPart5 = [event valueForKey:@"port5"];
    _strPart6 = [event valueForKey:@"port6"];
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey) out.

Comment: It was probably objectForKey and valueForKey that made the error.

Comment: Don't use `valueForKey` unless you know what KVC is and you really need its functionality.

Comment: @vadian could you direct us to some good documentation about KVC and make us understand what it means. This would be helpful.

Comment: Short description: [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KeyValueCoding.html). The dedicated method to get a value from a dictionary is `objectForKey:` or key subscripting (`event["port1"]`)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *dict= [responce valueforkey:@"portitems"];
NSMutableArray *portitems1=[dict valueForKey:@"port1"];
 NSMutableArray *portitems2=[dict valueForKey:@"port2"];
NSMutableArray *portitems3=[dict valueForKey:@"port3"];
NSMutableArray *portitems4=[dict valueForKey:@"port4"];
NSMutableArray *portitems5=[dict valueForKey:@"port5"];
```

Comment: Here response means means result dictionary object.