# I want to replace Json values to another string values in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

Using Json I have retrieve some values to UITableViewCell

```
NSString *sample = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"food"];
```

I am getting 1,2,3,4,6 in my sample string values

But I want to show like, if for example `1=apple 2=grape 3=orange 4=pineapple 5=lemon 6=All`

I want the result to be `apple,grape,orange,pineapple,All` in my sample string values

Comment: Please share your json and expected result.

Comment: I am getting like this from json "food":"1,2,3,4,6",but I want to replace 1,2,3,4,6 into apple,grape,orange,pineapple,All and if food values is "food":"1,2" and I want to show apple,grape in tableviewcell

Comment: @micMacSolutions Use enum

Comment: @micMacSolutions Yes that I understand but where? Please share your json data and the node where you want to replace this.

Comment: `Objective-C` doesn't has `String` type enums. So if you elaborate more then I can answer accordingly.

Comment: Tell me exact what you need?

Comment: @micMacSolutions The `json data` and how do you want to replace.. as `String` or just want to identify 1 as apple ?

Comment: @TheTiger yes I just want to show another string based on that sample string value

Comment: 1=apple 2=grape 3=orange 4=pineapple 5=lemon 6=All  if food values is "food":"1" I want to show "apple" in my new string, if food values is "food":"2"  I want to show "grape",if food values is "food":"1,2"  I want to show "apple,grape" in my new string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Objective-C` there is no built in `enums` available for `String` types. You can declare `enums` as `Integer` and then make a function or an array of strings which return the string value for that `enum`.

Declare in your `.h` file.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FRUIT) {
    APPLE = 1,
    GRAPE,
    ORANGE,
    PINEAPPLE,
    LEMON,
    All
};

extern NSString * const FRUITString[];
```

Define in your `.m` file.

```
NSString * const FRUITString[] = {
    [APPLE] = @"APPLE",
    [GRAPE] = @"GRAPE",
    [ORANGE] = @"ORANGE",
    [PINEAPPLE] = @"PINEAPPLE",
    [LEMON] = @"LEMON",
    [All] = @"All"
};
```

and you can use it like:

```
NSLog(@"%@", FRUITString[APPLE]);
// OR
NSLog(@"%@", FRUITString[1]);
```

> **Output:** APPLE

**Based on your comment:** *if food values is "food":"1,2" I want to show "apple,grape"*

```
NSString *foodValue = @"1,2";
NSArray *values = [foodValue componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableArray *stringValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *value in values) {
    [stringValues addObject:FRUITString[[value integerValue]]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", [stringValues componentsJoinedByString:@","]);
```

> APPLE,GRAPE

Comment: @micMacSolutions Glad it helped you. Please accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Define a NSDictionary with your required mapping, and fetch the value from your mapping dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *foodDict = @{
  @"1": @"apple",
  @"2": @"grape",
  @"3": @"orange",
  @"4": @"pineapple",
  @"5": @"lemon",
  @"6": @"all"
};

NSString *sample = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"food"];

NSString *sampleValue= [foodDict valueForKey:sample];
```

"sampleValue" is your required String Value needed. (Cast it to NSString if required)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code  **objectForKey@""** to **valueForKey@""**

```
NSString *sample = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"food"];
```

Comment: This is the wrong way to fetch the key. We should not use `valueForKey:`. `objectForKey:` is right way.

Comment: If we want to get the value inside the key "food" we need to use valueForKey:

Comment: You really need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey) then. Don't miss this.